# How to remove commits from master without 'revert' or 'rebase' commands?

Tags: git, git-commit

I have a **master** branch. I want to remove the commits from the point of a previous commit which was two weeks ago to this point from the **master** branch.

I can't use `git revert` due to an existing revert already in that branch and will cause issues. I'm looking for a solution to point the **HEAD** to a previous commit or **SHA1** in the **master** branch and set that **SHA1** as the master.

Comment: Please show the commit graph you have and the one you want.  Thinking about git operations any other way tends to generate confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm looking a solution to point the HEAD to a previous commit and say that is the master.

That is what `reset` does, when the current branch is `master`:

```
git reset SHA1
```

This will reset the current branch so that it will point to the specified SHA1 (commit, branch, tag, tree-ish). Note that your working tree will not change, so if it is different from the content as of SHA1, then `git diff` will show changed and/or unversioned files. If you want the working tree to match the content of the SHA1, then use the `--hard` flag.

Note that if you want to push this changed branch to a remote where you already pushed it before, you will need to use the `-f` flag with `git push`, as the history has been rewritten.
Keep in mind the usual concerns when rewriting the history of a public branch.